# ravendb remove multiple versions of the same document

Tags: ravendb

I have a database with version bundle turned on. So the documents were saved like:
 user/1/revision/1, user/1/revision/2, etc.
But what I didnt expect is that on search I will have all the versions of the same user or whatever else document I deal with.
I tried to restore this db to a new database with version bundle turned on and off and I still have all the versions in search.

I make search like this:
`session.Query<Entity>().Search(x=>x.Name, query, options: SearchOptions.And, escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.AllowPostfixWildcard)`

Not sure, maybe I should use some specific parameters to work with latest document version only?

UPDATE:
What I did so far:

- reinstalled ravendb and installed it as a service(it was as a service, just made sure I didnt break anything)
- imported data from old database to new database
- deleted all the indexes related to the entity

I still get all the revisions in my search results. Also my Raven.Server.config doesnt have anything related to bundles. My raven version is 2750 which seem to be the latest production release recommended.

UPDATE 2: When I try to import data to new database from old dump I get the following error:

Client side exception:

### System.Exception: Server Error:

/bulk_docs
Raven.Abstractions.Exceptions.OperationVetoedException: PUT vetoed by Raven.Bundles.Versioning.Triggers.VersioningPutTrigger because: Modifying a historical revision is not allowed
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.AssertPutOperationNotVetoed(String key, RavenJObject metadata, RavenJObject document, TransactionInformation transactionInformation)
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c_*DisplayClass4b.b*_43(IStorageActionsAccessor actions)
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action)
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Put(String key, Etag etag, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata, TransactionInformation transactionInformation)
   at Raven.Database.Extensions.CommandExtensions.Execute(ICommandData self, DocumentDatabase database, BatchResult batchResult)
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.ProcessBatch(IList`1 commands)
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c_*DisplayClass10c.b*_108(IStorageActionsAccessor actions)
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.ExecuteBatch(Action`1 action, EsentTransactionContext transactionContext)
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action)
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Batch(IList`1 commands)
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.DocumentBatch.Batch(IHttpContext context)
   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.DispatchRequest(IHttpContext ctx)

### at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.HandleActualRequest(IHttpContext ctx)

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Revisions shouldn't be indexed. As long as the versioning bundle is active on the database and the revision documents have a metadata key `Raven-Document-Revision-Status` with value `Historical` they should be ignored by all indexed.

Check the bundle is active on that DB, and the metadata mentioned above exists.

This holds true for 2.0, 2.5 and iirc 1.0 as well.

Comment: Going to check now. Are there any steps to fix that in case version bundle was off? I'm fine to create a new database etc. Just need to get rid of lot of similiar results in a search.

Comment: Ive created a new db, imported the old one, with version bundle turned on. Added "Raven-Document-Revision-Status":"Historical" to version bundle configuration for this entity. Its still all the version in the search. I even deleted the indexes and started them over. Any ideas?

Comment: If the indexes were created after the bundle was turned on and all metadata is in place, I'd report this as a bug. Here's the code in question - as you can see, its just 2 simple rules: https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Database/Bundles/Versioning/Triggers/HideVersionedDocumentsFromIndexingTrigger.cs

Comment: I also noticed I dont have Raven.Server.exe.config have any versioning bundle related data. And according to this:http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/configuration
it should be some settings related to this active bundle. Or am I missing anything? Do I need to add anything else in config, except for just checking the versioning bundle when creating a new database?

Comment: depending on the version you use, the versioning bundle has to be explicitly enabled for a database (and in v1.0 you have to have the DLL in the plugins folder). Just make sure you did that.

Comment: Read my update. I put everything I did to fix it. Also specified my version. I do not have anything in my plugin directory, but it seems its not required for v2750 that I have.

Comment: As I said, if you followed the instructions above and this still happens you should probably report this as a bug.